# Compiz on 16.04 LTS with two minitors moves window randomly between workspaces and monitors

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, compiz, workspaces

If I use the launcher to get to an already open application, windows get jumbled, often landing in the top left workspace on the primary screen.

If a window gets minimised it is rather random where it surfaces and what gets jumbled.

When the system came up the monitors were arranged in the wrong left-right order in the settings panel, so I shifted the two monitors.  No other tweaks or add-ons.

This is not particularly useful.  Anyone knows of a window manager that works in this environment?  (Apart from Tom's Window Manager.)